# Which revolutions in topology and geometry can we expect in the next 20 years?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, big-list, big-picture

In my limited perspective on the history of mathematics, I can name at least two big revolutions in Topology and Geometry (broadly construed): the introduction of Schemes in Algebraic Geometry, and the introduction of $\infty$-categories in Homotopy Theory. By "revolution" I mean a new formal framework to approach problems in a given branch of mathematics such that:

1. Previous results can be reformulated in the new framework, at least partially.
2. Its introduction brings substantial insight and advancement to that area.
3. It usually requires much effort to be studied, but once obtained it provides an efficient and systematic toolkit to approach problems in the same branch.

Some of these revolutions divide the experts, whether temporarily or permanently; it could be the case that an alternative perspective makes some aspects of the theory clearer so that two frameworks can (usually with struggle) cohabit. I still count that as a 'revolution'. Let me also specify that (sub-)sub-branches are allowed and encouraged. For example, a similar shift can be seen in Knot Theory when Vassiliev began to study the cohomology of the (infinite-dimensional) space of embeddings $S^1 \to S^3$ instead of single, hand-crafted invariants on such space. It is not as radical as schemes though, since some aspects are not (yet) satisfactorily reformulated in this context.

Since revolutions are to some extent unexpected contributions, it is hard to predict them. However, I think they are not (only) the invention of a bright mathematician, but existing conditions in the mathematical 'ground' help them to stem.

To limit the subjectivity of the answers, which will be inevitable to a certain degree, I have chosen two indicators that the ground is fertile for such a revolution to happen:

1. A sub-branch that has several interesting examples, tricks, and results, which lacks at the moment a clear pattern of strategies and a coherent formalism to explain them;
2. A sub-branch in which formal aspects became a subject of research on its own, but no satisfactory results in terms of cohesion and efficacy have been found.

Regarding (1), I guess algebraic geometry felt a bit like that before Grothendieck. On the other hand, I see (2) happening often, e.g., in category theory, and sometimes there is a struggle to find a nice reformulation. However, some axiomatizations become accepted in time, and several models are discovered to fit the same axiomatization. I find e.g. the development of cohomology theories very rewarding from this point of view, with the study of representing spectra becoming a new focus and boosting (or initiating?) the study of the stable homotopy category.

**Remark.** I did my best to make this question objective, and I would like to avoid advertisements of some areas of mathematics over some others. I understand if the question will be voted to close since big-list are quite controversial, but I think I would learn a lot from answers, so I'd give anyway a try. I also have a practical motivation: new theories usually require a lot of hours of studying to be mastered, and I'd be happier to avoid that... despite being curious about their content if they are satisfactory!

Regarding branches, I am mostly interested in algebraic topology and anything in this neighborhood, but I would be happy to listen from other geometers (e.g. differential). I think opening to other areas would make the question too broad.

Comment: I'd add, to your list of past revolutions in Geometry: Euclid's Elements, coordinates (analytic geometry), projective geometry, unprovability of the parallel postulate, geometry over fields other than the reals.

Comment: Big list, subjective questions should generally be CW. You can edit and check the box to make it so. See, for example: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4112/when-answers-are-primarily-opinion-based-should-the-question-be-cw

Comment: @DavidWhite No, that's not true. You can't mark a question CW. Only moderators can. You can mark an answer that you are posting as CW. But that's different.

Comment: Circles, and not just in the next 20 years.

Comment: @DavidWhite to complement Asaf's comment: one could make one's own question CW before, but it changed (maybe 5 years ago?). So the solution, both for OP and for you as a reader, is to flag asking the post to be made CW.

Comment: Differential geometry is a huge omission. In my view, there was a revolution sparked by the work of Taubes and Uhlenbeck which led directly to Donaldson’s spectacular work. Parallel to that were more geometric approaches developed by many but perhaps most spectacularly by Gromov. Yau and Schoen, among others used all of this and more to build a new area, now called geometric analysis, and connected it to topology. Hamilton also came along and launched a revolution within a revolution using geometric heat flows, which culminated in Perelman's proof of the Thurston conjecture.

Comment: Isn't it a little odd to have a question about geometry that doesn't have a single tag with the word "geometry"?

Comment: From my limited perspective, revolutions come out of nowhere and blindside everyone. So they're rather hard to predict. I'm also older and I don't know that much about algebraic geometry. But it seems to me that the revolution in algebraic geometry and topology really originated in the introduction of category theory itself. It originated as an abstract seemingly empty framework for organizing proofs in algebraic topology. But it turned into much more than I think anyone imagined it would. There certainly have been revolutions within this, but I think you have to start there.

Comment: The title doesn’t seem to have much to do with the non-geometric examples the OP has in mind.  Also, “revolutions” are almost by definition not things you can predict.  All you are going to get as answers are breathless invocations of whatever is being hyped at this moment.  I entered grad school 22 years ago, and there is almost no relationship between what was being hyped then and what actually lead to advances in the intervening years.  I have therefore voted to close.

Comment: @Deane Yang: to my surprise, tunless I am screwing something up, there is no tag "geometry". Free to edit if I am wrong!

Comment: @Andy Putman: I am not sure I emphasized this enough, but my stress is on language and formal changes more than on results and discoveries. As I mentioned, my motivation is: will I still be able to *read* geometric articles being published in a neighborhood of algebraic topology without studying too much background? For example, if I got my PhD fifteen years ago, I guess I would have struggled a bit to learn infinity categories in the spare time (I am considering to leave academia). I found it nice to include big perspective shifts in the question, which have an interest oon their own.

Comment: @AndreaMarino: I don't think those are any more predictable.

Comment: The question has been closed for reason "not about research level mathematics" but I think that's an error, so I voted to reopen. The OP is a research mathematician who makes clear that he wants to know which areas to focus his time on, to stay up to date with developments, because these areas are likely to be related to future research. The question is +17/-9. The comments make it seem like the votes to close have to do with a lack of geometric examples or the idea that the question is hard to answer. But, I do think it's about research level mathematics.

Comment: I agree that the question is research level, so I guess it should be closed for other reasons (e.g. subjectivity). Nevertheless, I take the closing act as an indirect answer to the question "Can we predict ..?" with a bold "We can't". I theoretically disagree, but there are many experienced researchers that expressed this opinion, so I guess in practice it is very hard (probably, it is only possible in hindsight). Also, I am glad not to open MO to handle controversy, so I agree with its closure.

Comment: The reason I don't think this question is appropriate for here is because I don't think it is really answerable. It asks us to guess about the future. A question like "which of the six remaining Millennium Prize problems will be resolved next?" would similarly be inappropriate (even if it is clearly *about* research math in a certain sense).

Comment: I voted to close the question for exactly the reason Sam Hopkins stated, which I also expressed in my comments (the non-geometric nature of the examples was more of an aside in those comments).  Whenever I vote to close, I always choose "not about research level mathematics" as the reason, which I interpret as "inappropriate for MO".  Obsessing about the minutia of exactly which closing justification on the list most closely matches the actual issue with the question seems to me like a poor use of one's time.

Comment: @AndyPutman FWIW I voted to close (with no malice intended towards the OP) selecting the "Opinion-based" option. I think that a lot of these narratives get written in hindsight, and overemphasise "breakthroughs" and "revolutions" while ignoring lots of the incremental work that provides the soil in which dramatic ideas can take root

Comment: @YemonChoi: I agree, and I concur I also voted without intending any malice towards the OP.

Comment: I very much appreciate folks putting their reasons for voting to close here and below my answer. I cannot help but point out that a casual reader of MO is seeing a pretty wild variation in terms of when the "opinion based" closure reason is invoked and when such questions are left to dominate the front page. I wrote about this a month ago on Meta. For me, the OP being a research mathematician, and the research focus of the question (only have finite time; not sure what best to study) makes all the difference, compared to a big list for its own sake.

Comment: @YemonChoi: I don't think changes in perspective and language are narrative-based, but I agree that the conditions allowed the change to happen. I made that point in my question, and I was exactly trying to ask for "which soil is preparing a shift?". As a metaphor, there are people studying the same in geopolitics; it is very hard to predict the future, but the discussion is nevertheless worthwhile. People writing the past (and the narrative) work in a different field.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the OP that it's difficult to predict revolutions. But I think [condensed mathematics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/condensed+mathematics) is an area worth paying careful attention to, given the powerful results it's already been used to prove, and the potential for even deeper results connecting geometry, topology, and number theory.

[This MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425598/what-actually-is-the-idea-behind-the-condensed-mathematics) gives some good motivation for condensed mathematics. Quoting from Tim Chow:

> The starting point is the observation that the traditional way of endowing something with both a topology and an algebraic structure has some shortcomings. The simplest example is that topological abelian groups do not form an abelian category.

The [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/condensed+mathematics) explains several uses of this new field, within the past couple of years, including to "the geometrization of the local Langlands correspondence" and to analytic geometry.  A bunch of references can be found on [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444608/reference-request-for-condensed-math). Also, [these lecture notes](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf) are a good place to learn. I should also mention that the theory of [pyknotic sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pyknotic+set) by Barwick and Haine is related.

Condensed mathematics has recently been invented by [Peter Scholze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Scholze) and co-authors. Scholze won a Fields Medal in 2018 for "transforming arithmetic algebraic geometry over p-adic fields through his introduction of [perfectoid spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectoid_space), with application to Galois representations, and for the development of new cohomology theories." He also wrote a [great answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65729/what-are-perfectoid-spaces/66563#66563) about perfectoid spaces, which is another potential revolution.

Lastly, unrelated to the above, [recent work](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01507) of Abouzaid and Blumberg provide a new way of thinking about Floer homology. [Here's an article in Quanta about it](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-transcend-geometric-theory-of-motion-20211209/) that seems to suggest it could be revolutionary.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph: Floer theory as a whole seems to me to be an under-appreciated revolution in (a certain part of) geometry. For that matter, Morse theory many decades earlier was its own revolution. But I suppose a list like this risks including all techniques...

Comment: Oh yeah, I probably should have mentioned Morse theory. Also, all the stuff about topological and geometric data analysis! But, my MO time for the day is over and now I have to go do much less fun work :-(

Comment: Your "[recent work] of Abouzaid and Blumberg" link goes to `https://Arnold%20Conjecture%20and%20Morava%20K-theory`, which seems probably unintentional.  Was it meant to be https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01507, [Abouzaid and Blumberg - Arnold conjecture and Morava K-theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01507)?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, thanks. I fixed this.

Comment: This answer is +6/-7 at the moment, with no comments as to why it was downvoted (unless people were really upset about a broken link in the first version). I assume the downvotes are either personal (this seems to happen a lot) or because people don't like the question. But, I don't think there's anything mathematically wrong in this answer, and I do think it's a good idea for young researchers to be aware of Scholze's Fields Medal winning work and its potential applications.

Comment: I +1'd this answer, but in terms of constructive criticism: I prefer when MO answers, even to "asking for a big list of examples" questions, only contain a single example. So the answer might be improved simply by removing the last paragraph and focusing solely on condensed math (which I believe *is* a good example of "a new perspective that might prove revolutionary in the future, although we don't know yet"). But I also think this question as a whole is off-topic, so maybe the whole discussion is moot...

Comment: @DavidWhite: I don't think there is any danger of young people not hearing about the work of Peter Scholze.  I downvoted because (like I predicted in my comments above) this doesn't answer the unanswerable question the OP asked, but just lists some currently fashionable "hot" ideas.